# jquery function that select an anchor with specific class

Tags: jquery, bind, anchor

In my sitemap I have several anchors inside table cells...

```
<table class="table_site">
    <tr>
        <td class="subsite"><a class="l1" href="#">link1</a></td>
        <td class="subsite"><a class="l2" href="#">link2</a></td>
        <td class="subsite"><a class="l3" href="#">link3</a></td>
        <td class="subsite"><a class="l4" href="#">link4</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've got an jquery script to call to any function switching anchor clicked.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $('a.l1').bind('click', function () {
    //code here
    });
</script>
```

It's not working at all

How can I call to specific anchor??

Thank you

Comment: Add the code within [`$(document).ready(function(){ $('a.l1 .... }); })`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), or use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/): ` `$(document).on('click', 'a.l1', function () { /* code  */ });`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon where you are placing the javascript, it may be running before the DOM is created.  Bind will only be active for elements that existed in the DOM when the method was called.  You need to make your call within a   $(document).ready(function() {}); call.  This will insure that bind occurs only when all the DOM has loaded.

Another suggestion is that you do not use bind.  As I mentioned, it will not bind itself to items created after the method is called.  It is better to use either live() (pre-jQuery1.7) or on() (post-jquery 1.7).  Here is a sample using on:

```
$(function () { $(".table_site").on("click", "a.l1", function(e) { ... do stuff ...});});
```

Answer (score 1):

its happening coz the DOM(Document Object Model) is not ready.Try this sniplet

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.l1').click(function(){
        //code logic goes here
    });
});
```

if anchor tag are generated on the fly,i.e by manipulating DOM by javascript then use `.on()` instead of `.click()` method
Also note that if u using jQuery version older than 1.7 the use `.delegate()` instead of `.on()` coz latter function works only with jQuery 1.7+